# Exporting spouses only exports one side of relationship

Tags: relationships, export

When I export a list of contacts and I include data about their spouse, the spouse data is included for only one of the contacts. Like so:

`Name           Spouse Name     City
Sam Smith       Linda Smith     Tulsa
Linda Smith                     Tulsa`

I can't find anywhere that indicates this is proper behavior. Is it by design? Bug?

[image: "Spouse of" fields in the export]

Comment: Not clear what you mean. I see Sam and i see Linda. What is missing? Maybe add screenshots of your Export mapping

Comment: I think the issue is that the row for Sam shows Linda, but the row for Linda does not show Sam.  How are you doing the export? How are you recording spouse (eg as a relationship, a custom field ...)

Comment: Yes, what Aidan said. I am recording it as a standard Civi relationship. I am doing a fairly standard Contacts export where I select fields, which include several "Spouse of" relationship fields. I'll see about including some screen shots.

Comment: can you explain why you need the rows for both ends of the relationship? If you have all the fields you need about Sam, and all the fields you need about his Spouse does it matter much? ie not sure if this is just awkward or actually preventing you do what you want. or is the issue more 'how can i do a search to only find those at end A rather than end B" (eg change B name 'spouse of' to 'spouse is' just so you can select only those at end A (this may sound goobledegook -if so let me know and i will expand in an Answer)

Comment: Well, I'm finding what I need for my current use, but I guess I don't think that one needs a reason why the output should be what one would reasonably expect when exporting spouse data. If I export hundreds of contacts to a spreadsheet and then look at only one line, I would think that Sam Smith doesn't have a spouse; that is wrong information. More importantly, if my export includes Sam Smith but not Linda, Sam's spouse data isn't in my exported data set at all. (This same behavior applies to "Friend of" relationships and presumably others where A>B and B>A language is the same.)

Comment: This conversation has helped me understand a bit more about how relationship exports work (i.e. only from A to B, even if B to A has the same language). I think the distinction is overly obscure for the typical end user, and would suggest that built-in relationships be set up with different language for each side, e.g. "Spouse of" and "Spouse is", and that the documentation (https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/relationships/) discourages the same descriptors to avoid future confusion. That at least makes what's going on here more transparent.